Update p-table view not change when update array
I have an structure p-table, but  when change my arrray value, the table dont any change, same array in console appear one value e in tbale is display how more iten in table
This is my function to the update array
 getPromocoesPorNome(event:any) {
    if(this.nameSearch == '' ){
      this.getPromocoes()

    }
    this.promolistService.getPromocaoByNome(this.nameSearch).pipe(finalize(() => { })).subscribe((response) => {
      console.log(this.promoData)
      this.promoData = []
      return this.promoSearch =[response];

    },
      (e) => {
      })

  }

this is my structure table
 <p-table [value]="promoData" responsiveLayout="stack" [breakpoint]="'960px'" [tableStyle]="{'min-width': '50rem'}"  [paginator]="true"
        [rows]="4"
        [showCurrentPageReport]="true"
        [tableStyle]="{ 'min-width': '50rem' }"
        currentPageReportTemplate="Exibindo {first} até {last} para {totalRecords} resultados encontrados">
            <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
                <tr>
                    <th>Nome</th>
                    <th>Url</th>
                    <th>Divulgador</th>
                    <th>Data de Publicação</th>
                    <th>Produto</th>
                    <th>Detalhes</th>
                    <th>Valor</th>
                    <th>Ações</th>

                </tr>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-promoData>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{promoData.nome}}</td>
                    <td><a href="{{promoData.url}}" target="_blank">{{promoData.url}}</a></td>
                    <td>{{promoData.divulgador}}</td>
                    <td>{{formatarData(promoData.data_publicacao)}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            <div *ngFor="let produto of promoData.produtos">
                                {{produto.nome}} ({{produto.categoria}})
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p-tag [value]="getValueInfo(promoData.data_publicacao)" [severity]="getSeverity(promoData.data_publicacao)"></p-tag>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            <div *ngFor="let produto of promoData.produtos">
                                R$ {{produto.valor}}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="delete-product" (click)="deletarPromocao(promoData.pk_promocao)"> <i class="pi pi-trash" style="color: red"></i></button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ng-template>
        </p-table>

I need that table change view according to array

The use of finalize is not good. Use tap operator instead.
(Dont mutate data, be more declarative, dont forget to unsubscribe, and please code in english.)

So , i change the code  but same problem continue, still not change the array
